# MYSQL SUM() in one table and JOIN with 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I have 3 tables: `items`, `purchases`, and `collaborators`. A user can own an item, purchase an item, or be a collaborator on an item. Additionally, items that are purchased can be rated up, `+1`, or down, `-1`. An owner or collaborator can't purchase their own item.

I'd like to get all items for a given user and also display the ratings on each item.

Here's my tables:

```
      items           |           purchases           |     collaborators
i_id  item_id user_id | p_id item_id  user_id  rating |c_id item_id user_id
  1      1       11   |  1      1         13     -1   |  1     1        12 
  2      2       12   |  2      2         11      1   |  2     2        13
  3      3       13   |  3      3         12     NULL |    
                      |  4      1         14     -1   |
```

Here's my MYSQL query so far:

```
select *, count(p_id) as tots, sum(rating=1) as yes, sum(rating= '-1') as no
from items
left join purchases
on items.item_id=purchases.item_id
left join collaborators
on items.item_id=collaborators.item_id
where items.user_id=13 or purchases.user_id=13 or collaborators.user_id=13
group by items.item_id
```

Here's my expected results for `user_id=11` (changing **each** `user_id` in the `WHERE` clause):

```
item_id    tots  yes no
  1         2     0   2
  2         1     1   0
// notice how user_id=11 doesn't have anything to do with item_id=3
```

Here's my expected results for `user_id=12`:

```
item_id    tots  yes no
  1         2     0   2
  2         1     1   0    
  3         1     1   0
```

Here's my expected results for `user_id=13`:

```
item_id    tots  yes no
  1         2     0   2
  2         1     1   0    
  3         1     1   0   
//notice user_id=13 should have same results as user_id=12. Although, their 
relation to each of the 3 items is different, they still either purchased, 
own, or collaboratored on each of them.
```

Unfortunately, I get the first two results but not the correct one for `user_id=13`.
For `user_id=13, item_id=1` the `tots=1` and not `tots=2` for some reason I can't understand.

Any thoughts, such as, "its better to separate this into 2 queries", would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: In your `purchases` table, there *is* only one item_id for user_id 13?! Why do you expect it to return 2 io 1?

Comment: hi @Lieven, thanks,  b/c i want to count the purchases/ratings for each item regardless of who purchased them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirly sure I understand you correct but you could try following statement and let us work from there.

**Edit**

Following statement returns the expected results.
[You can verify this *(using SQL Server)* here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/73520/81723/mysql-sum-in-one-table-and-join-with-2-other-tables).

The gist of this is to

- select all possible user_id and item_id combinations from your three tables
- select the counts/ratings for each item
- combine the results

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT u.user_id, pt.item_id, pt.cnt, pt.yes, pt.no
FROM   (
        SELECT user_id, item_id, title FROM items 
        UNION SELECT user_id, item_id, NULL FROM purchases
        UNION SELECT user_id, item_id, NULL FROM collaborators      
       ) u INNER JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
               , SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(rating, 1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes
               , SUM(CASE WHEN rating =-1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no
               , item_id
        FROM   purchases
        GROUP BY
               item_id
      ) pt ON pt.item_id = u.item_id
```

**MYSQL statement**

```
SELECT u.user_id, pt.item_id, pt.cnt, pt.yes, pt.no, u.title
FROM   (
    SELECT user_id, item_id, title FROM items where user_id=13
    UNION SELECT user_id, item_id, NULL FROM purchases where user_id=13
    UNION SELECT user_id, item_id, NULL FROM collaborators where user_id=13       
   ) u INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
           , SUM(rating=1) AS yes
           , SUM(rating =-1) AS no
           , item_id
    FROM   purchases 
    GROUP BY
           item_id
  ) pt ON pt.item_id = u.item_id
```

Comment: @timpeterson - I have altered the statement and added some explanation. You didn't add an expected result for user_id 14 but I assume it should be present in the output.

Comment: -@Lieven oh cool, thanks for the tip on the SE data explorer, I hadn't know of that.  I'm looking to have a WHERE clause so I added this to your answer and also changed the `SUM` part to make it work in MYSQL. The bottom line is it works, so awesome stuff! One last question, is this too computationally costly of a query? Should I be looking to refactor in some way? I'm not experienced with SQL so I have no idea if this is a reasonable query or not. It looks pretty scary to me. thanks for your help!

Comment: @timpeterson - That very much depends on the amount of records in your tables but in the end, you will have to look at the execution plan to know what the bottlenecks are. I wouldn't expect any problems on a decent indexed database and if you always select for a single user, I would add the where clause to each individual select statement from items, purchases and collaborators so to minimize the amount of records MySQL has to juggle with.

Comment: -@Lieven thanks, i added those WHERE clauses to my answer. And thanks for the thoughts on DB structure. I'm only building my site now so hopefully the records in each table will grow alot but can't say for sure.

Comment: -@Lieven I'm realizing that the `UNION` eliminates any unique fields from my 3 tables. For example, an item has a `title` but I can't access it b/c it creates an unequal # of columns and my `purchases` and `collaborators` tables don't have this field.  Do you have any thoughts on how to work around this?

Comment: @timpeterson - You would add a placeholder to each select not containing the column you like to add. I have altered you **MYSQL statement** in my answer to add a `title` and placeholder columns.

Comment: -@Lieven,  oh cool this is great to know, i hadn't thought of that, can add more than one `NULL` if need more than 1 unique value too, thanks!